# Unable to convert GML to shapefile in ArcGIS Pro Data Interoperability Quick Export option

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, gml, data-interoperability

I am trying to import GML file and convert it to shapefile in ArcGIS Pro Data Interoperability Quick Export option. However, I got the error

> XML Parser error: 'Error at file: '' line: 0 column: 0 message: unable to open primary document entity 'C:\Users\HOJordanStudent\Documents\ArcGIS\Projects\HK_Population_Census_2021\ImportLog\LSBG2021_Boundary.xsd''

The download file does not exist the file LSBG2021_Boundary.xsd. Are there any directions to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If ArcGIS Pro requires the schema file I suggest to use the GDAL GML driver https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html. It does not require xsd https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gml.html#schema.

> In contrast to most GML readers, the OGR GML reader does not require
> the presence of an XML Schema definition of the feature classes (file
> with .xsd extension) to be able to read the GML file. If the .xsd file
> is absent or OGR is not able to parse it, the driver attempts to
> automatically discover the feature classes and their associated
> properties by scanning the file and looking for “known” gml objects in
> the gml namespace to determine the organization. While this approach
> is error prone, it has the advantage of working for GML files even if
> the associated schema (.xsd) file has been lost.

You can use the GDAL GML driver by installing GDAL command line utilities of through QGIS.

Comment: I will first try on this. Thanks